# Pipe the heads of two files to a file

Tags: bash, shell

Quite often I want to take the first 1000 lines of one file, say, the first 200 of another  and pipe the concatenation  to a file.

To do  this I can do

```
head -1000 fileA > fileA-1000
head -200 fileB > fileB-200

cat fileB-200 fileA-1000 > file C
```

Is it possible to do this all as one command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{ head -200 fileB; head -1000 fileA; } > fileC
```

One can group commands together with `{...}`.  Once the commands are grouped, then I/O redirection can be applied to the group as a whole.

Comment: Thank you. What does the second semi-colon do?

Comment: The shell treats `}` as the end-of-group marker _only_ if it is the first word of a command.  If the second semi-colon was not there, by contrast, the shell would think that `}` was the last argument to the `head -200 fileB` command.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. You have the files listed in the opposite order to me (A then B not B then  A). Is that deliberate?

Comment: @eleanora No, sorry, not deliberate.  Answer updated with correct order.